# How to use triggers with functions that require parameters from the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I found a simple and great solution to [retrieve JSON into a Google spreadsheet](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json).

**I want the function `ImportJSON` to update regularly via a trigger** (event or time-based, I still haven't decided what I will use). The problem with using [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), be it an onChange or time based trigger, is that it runs the script directly - it does not tell the spreadsheet to run the script. Since **the script depends on input from the spreadsheet** (the function requires at least one parameter - an URL), **any type of trigger will fail with**:

```
13-11-17 18:15:50:940 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[13-11-17 18:15:51:011 PST] Starting execution
[13-11-17 18:15:51:020 PST] UrlFetchApp.fetch([[object Object], null]) [0 seconds]
[13-11-17 18:15:51:065 PST] Execution failed: Invalid argument: http://[object%20Object] (line 167, file "Code") [0.044 seconds total runtime]
```

*I could attach a trigger to a wrapper function*, which takes no arguments, and have that wrapper function pass the parameter to `ImportJSON`. But since I have dozens of sheets within the document (dozens of URLs to retrieve JSON from), I'd have to create one wrapper function per sheet. This looks like a clumsy solution.

I wish I could make the spreadsheet run the script and update the values, but I don't think this is possible. **There has to be a better way to use triggers with functions that require parameters from the spreadsheet.**

Comment: Have you looked into the _event_ object? Your event handler method is passed an event object, which in many cases (depending on the event type) contains a reference to the spreadsheet, so you can fetch values from it. See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) from the Apps Script docs. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use triggers with functions that require parameters from the spreadsheet?

AFAIK, you cannot. The solution is to create one single function, for example called `RefreshAll`, inside which you call all the wrapper functions (`GetValue`) containing the actual parameters which need to be passed to the function that actually does the job (`RealFunctionThatDoesTheJob`).

*Note: Sorry if this sounds complicated. If you only have one set of parameters (as opposed to 3, in the example below), you can do away with `GetValue` and call `RealFunctionThatDoesTheJob` directly from within the function that is being triggered (`RefreshAll`).*

Lastly, to have your triggers send to your spreadsheet those values that are dependent on parameters, you need to have the script *push* the values to the spreadsheet using (`currentSheet.getRange(Row,Column).setValue(Value);`)

Here is the example:

```
function RefreshAll() {

  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("MySheet");

  var Value1 = GetValue1();
  currentSheet.getRange(Row,Column).setValue(Value1);

  var Value2 = GetValue2();
  currentSheet.getRange(Row,Column).setValue(Value2);   

  var Value3 = GetValue3();
  currentSheet.getRange(Row,Column).setValue(Value3);

}

function GetValue1() {
  return RealFunctionThatDoesTheJob("Parameter1","Parameter2","Parameter3");
}

function GetValue2() {
  return RealFunctionThatDoesTheJob("Parameter4","Parameter5","Parameter6");
}

function GetValue3() {
  return RealFunctionThatDoesTheJob("Parameter7","Parameter8","Parameter9");
}
```